# Clarification of beta status

Tags: discussion, beta

Since many of you may not routinely follow the [global meta-meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), I wanted to point out an important recent meta-meta post about the status of [endless beta](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1112/why-are-we-still-in-beta) sites like ours:

[Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/132073)

The executive summary is:

1. We're not in any danger of being closed.
2. The rule of thumb for graduation is 10 questions/day. We presently average 4-6.

It is possible that we might remain in this "non-graduated" state for [a very long time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites#comment840165_257614). There is [an ongoing discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites?cb=1#comment840257_257630) within SE, and [on the meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257652/can-we-do-something-about-the-beta-label), about differentiating between the first 90 days "beta mode" and the kind of steady state sites like us find ourselves in. This has the potential to lead to some intermediate changes, such as removing the beta label, site elections, or minor site CSS tweaks, or... Everything is up for debate.

Comment: "Everything is up for debate" --> brings to mind "the only thing we know for sure is that we don't know anything for sure"...

Comment: I wish I knew what can be done. As it is it's mostly an MtG site (30% of all questions). When I have questions I come here, but I know that I get better answers at BGG. I'm not sure what is needed to change that.

Comment: @zespri I think the mechanics of asking and answering questions are better here than BGG.  What BGG has going for it is a large population, and participation from the actual creators of the games who can give authoritative answers.

Comment: I would say one of the big problems as it currently stands is that when a site goes from beta to live the pool of people who can help clean up the site shrinks by a large margin as all the requirements to perform actions increase by a large margin.

Comment: @bwarner But we're encouraged to search before posting questions.  And if most of the time I can find an answer on BGG, doesn't that mean I should not post my question?

Comment: To be fair, we've already BEEN in beta for a long time.  I just noticed that one of my answers was from December 2010.

Comment: I'm surprised that the hurdle faced is average 10 questions a day. The longer it drags though, it will be tougher to bring the average up due to the long duration.

Any intention to conduct a drive for members to actively ask question? I think I can come up with 30 questions a month, 10 other people would then already help us sustain that average for a month.